# Android - keeping the activity alive

Tags: android

I have a puzzling problem. If I deploy my application from Eclipse on any device/emulator, I can use the Back and Home buttons to minimize it and then I can click the launcher icon to resume it.

If I take the apk, put it on the phone and install it (using the Astro file manager), then press Back or Home, when I click the launcher icon again, my application will be recreated instead of resumed: the activity is not destroyed.

This goes against everything written about on the android developer website regarding activities and their lifecycle.

For instance, this is what I do when the user uses the Back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Yet my application is recreated when I click its launcher icon. Any ideas?

Comment: have a look at the activity lifecycle http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: `onResume()` is called. Check that.

Comment: Either the phone kills the app to free RAM (system can do it any time), or the activity is recreated because it is in different screen orientation. Use logcat, everything is there for you to analyse!

Answer (score 0):

This goes exactly with everything written about the activity life cycle.

> If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity
>   from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing its
>   process. When it is displayed again to the user, it must be completely
>   restarted and restored to its previous state.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

You application is not "minimised".  There is not such thing as minimised in Android.  It's not Linux or Windows or OSX.

Comment: Er, excuse me?  It uses a Linux kernel but Android is most certainly NOT a Linux distro.  Where's dev, Sys V or glibc?  Where is the open source repository for all of the user space components?

Comment: You might as well say "iOS is  UNIX".  I see many Android devs trying to treat Android like Linux and it's usually not a good result.

Comment: Android **is** a Linux distro (as well as a software stack). Of course it's not a traditional linux distro. iOS is a GUI on top of FreeBSD.

Comment: While this can be interpreted as randomly correct, it doesn't look so random when I have a system using 5% of my resources and displaying the exact same behavior (closing down my app) 100% of the times.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, pressing Back will kill your Activity. However, why is that a problem? Android provides a mechanism to save your Activity's state and be able to resume.

View the Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

This is a must read on saving Activity state: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState

Comment: Pressing Back doesn't kill my Activity. Please read what I wrote. It moves it to the back (moveTaskToBack) and when the launcher icon is clicked again, then the Activity gets recreated.